# ¿Como descargar un excel creado desde un datatable C#?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net, visual

Lo que pasa es que tengo una tabla de html, la cual se pueden filtrar los valores del tbody desde una fila del thead, el usuario debe poder descargar la información en un archivo de Excel.

El webservice restful que hace la tarea de convertir la información para poder descargarla es el siguiente: (pongo "..." porque son muchos campos, los cuales es excesivo ponerlo aquí)

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<FileResult> CrearExcel([FromQuery] string NombreArchivo, [FromBody] IEnumerable<FacturasCobrarViewModel_Excel> Tabla)
{
   DataTable dt = new DataTable(NombreArchivo);

   dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[]
   {
    new DataColumn("SerieFolio"),
    new DataColumn("Referencia"),
    ...
    new DataColumn("Estatus")
   });

   foreach (var item in Tabla)
   {
       dt.Rows.Add(
           item.SerieFolio,
           item.Referencia,
           ...
           item.Estatus
       );
   }

   using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
   {
       wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);

       using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
       {
           wb.SaveAs(stream);
           return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", NombreArchivo + ".xlsx");
       }
   }
}
```

El metodo ajax es el siguiente:

```
function Descargar() {
   var url = window.location.origin + "/api/ReportesFinanzas/";

   //Preparar la lista a enviar
   var tabla = [];

   var tabla_tbody = $("#tbFacturas").find("tbody tr.trFila:visible");

   if (tabla_tbody.length == 0) {
       objMensajes.Error("Error", "No hay información para descargar.");
       return false;
   }

   $("#tbFacturas tbody tr").each(function (index) {
       tabla.push({
           SerieFolio: $(this).children("td:eq(1)").text(),
           Referencia: $(this).children("td:eq(2)").text(),
           ...
           Estatus: $(this).children("td:eq(19)").text()
       });
   });    

   //Enviar la tabla al webservice
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url + "CrearExcel?Archivo=Facturas",
       data: JSON.stringify(tabla),
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       success: function (data) {
        
       },
       error: function (xhr, status, error) {
           alert("Error en el sistema", xhr.status + " - " + xhr.statusText + " - " + xhr.responseText);
       }
   });
}
```

Observaciones:

1. El metodo de jquery si llena correctamente el array que se envía al webservice
2. El webservice si recibe correctamente la tabla de tipo FromBody y el otro parametro de tipo FromQuery
3. El webservice se ejecuta correctamente
4. El resultado del webservice en ajax apunta a "success" pero no descarga nada

¿Me hace falta algo?

Comment: Relacionado: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67362870/3613462

Comment: Y porque no mejor creas el excel directamente con javascript??

Comment: No deberias devolver un FileStreamResult?